# show Toast mesage till video installation and play it

Tags: android, timer, android-handler

I am developing a Video Application in Android and my question is related to installing video.

Firstly I am checking if video is  saved in local memory, if it is, I play it from local memory.

If video doesn't exist in my android local memory I install it to local memory and play it.

What I am  trying to do is, if video doesn't exist in local memory wait until 10 second to install the video and show Toast message in activity "**Video updated please wait**"

After installation is completed, app plays the video.

I tried with  below code but I get an error.

How can I do this?

```
SDCardRootCheck = new File("/mnt/sdcard/" + "/videos/" + name3);

Log.i("SDCardCeck", "" + "" + SDCardRootCheck.exists());

if (!SDCardRootCheck.exists()) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Video uptaded please wait", 5000).show();

    downloadFiles(videoLink3, name3);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds 
            vw.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/videos/" + name3);
            vw.start();

        }
    }, 7000);

}else if(SDCardRootCheck.exists()){

    vw.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/videos/" + name3);
    vw.start();

    // video finish listener
    vw.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // not playVideo
            // playVideo();

            mp.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `but I get a error`.  Do you think it might be useful to tell us what the error is?

Comment: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/customizing-display-time-of-toast.html

Comment: My poblem isn't about toast message. My problem is wait to 10 second completing downloadFiles(videoLink3, name3); after play video

Comment: I got a error like this "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to change main thread and you try to run thread in main thread. Use `AsyncTask` it works in the background. Try the below code and call Asynctask `new DownloadTask(this).execute();` in `OnCreate()

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  {

  private ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

  private Context context;

  /**
   * 
   * @param context
   * @param pdfDoc the document of the PDF
   */
  public DownloadTask(Context context) {
      this.context = context;

      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {  
          progressDialog.setMessage("Video Güncelleniyorf...");
          progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
      downloadFiles(videoLink3, name3);
      return null;
      //download here
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        vw.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/videos/" + name3);
        vw.start();

        // video finish listener
        vw.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // not playVideo
                // playVideo();

                mp.start();
            }
        });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the User Interface on main thread from another thread.

You can't do it.

You can send a Broadcast message in your download thread to communicate with the activity, or you can use somenthing like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){   
    }
});
```

Also pay attention to [Toast.makeTest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) method.
The duration parameter can be LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG.

Comment: how can I do multithreading in onCreate() method. Once thread will downloads video, second thread will waits once thread to complete installiation video and play video